# P10 Outdoor RGB DIP LED Module

Tags: led, datasheet, led-matrix, dot-matrix-display

As I have to make driver for this matrix module, I have a big problem finding its schematic or datasheet. There are many similar modules on the internet, they are made in China. I'm making driver on our hardware engineer assumption, and its going very slow.

Anyone have any documents or worked with this type of modules?

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your request probably doesn't fall into the category of being an electrical/electronic engineering question.

Comment: Do you have other pictures? Do you have a model number? With just an image of the LED side (not the connector side) *nobody* can tell you how to wire the matrix.

Comment: I haven't found back side image of the module on the internet, model is P10-346RGB4S-QD-B.

Comment: Try here: http://www.stdfled.com/

Comment: Good luck Master Yoda, may the force be with you.

Comment: Q: Is this a shopping question? A: Only sort of - he wants to put a system together. He wants to know protocol, system , ... used. It happens that the best solution is to identify it and buy parts BUT this is not necessarily so. **BUT** ....

Comment: Q: Does this QA session leave a 'valuable' searchable internet artefact that can be located by the search engines, which is valuable over some years and will assist the $ making aim of the knowledge-base building activity. A: Yes. Definitely. Other people will search for HUB40 and for LED panel interfaces and their like. While not stunning, as is or with a bit of crafting this could be far from the least of the SE EE attractors of search engine traffic - the Gold Standard [tm].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel suggested [**This page**](http://www.stdfled.com/P_view.asp?pid=29) which looks very similar to yours but not mechanically identical, and there are others like it on the net (as you note).

The rear view shows rows of many probably identical ICS and a few others near the input connectors. If you had one of these 'in your hand' trhe IC types would tell you quite a lot.

However, Daniels page has the line "Module interface: HUB40"

HUB40 is an LED panel driving system and Asian sourced interface cards are widely available. It is reasonably likely that your system is "HUB40 based". A look at the connectors on the rear of your system would go a long way towards confirming this.

[Here is an example](http://www.linsnled.com/product/linsn-hub40a.html) of a HUB40 transmit card - cost $5.
And a page full of them [here](http://www.linsnled.com/led-hub-card.html) - same supplier
[etc](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-shipping-2PCS-lot-HUB40A-HUB40-led-trasfer-board-for-Receiving-card-RV801D-MRV300/136400_1721151754.html), [**etc !!!**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=hub40+led&es_sm=122&biw=1280&bih=841&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=2_JmVcX2IIyC8gWW6YPoAg&ved=0CDMQsAQ)

---

You belatedly mention HUB75. This is also an LED panel driving panel with many cards available

http://www.eagerled.com/pic/other/image/HUB75_Card_Interface_Definition.jpg

HUB75 TX pinout

[image]

Comment: HUB75 is used here.

Comment: @MasterYoda How long have you known that ? Do you mean the panel has a Hub75 interface? If so it is an utterly essential part of your question and should be added. Are there any other vital and valuable facts that yuou know but have no disclosed that others could use / have used to help you?